# Dynamically create elements and add to an array

Tags: vb.net

I'm calling an application service to receipt purchase orders. The code below works (with the hardcoded values), however I will be querying a table first to get the values and there could be any number of receipt lines. Using the query results below as an example, each line is created and then added to the array.

```
LineId   Amt   Inc  Units Name
-------------------------
 00001 611.00 702.65 1 EACH

 00002 327.50 376.62 1 EACH
```

---

```
Dim loOrder_Receipt_Line1 As New Public.PurchaseOrder.Order_Receipt_Line

            With loOrder_Receipt_Line1

            .LineId = "00001"    
            .ReceivedForeignAmt = 611.00    
            .ReceivedForeignAmtInc = 702.65    
            .ReceivedUnits1 = 1    
            .ReceivedUnits1Name = "EACH"   
        End With

Dim loOrder_Receipt_Line2 As New Public.PurchaseOrder.Order_Receipt_Line

        With loOrder_Receipt_Line2
            .LineId = "00002"   
            .ReceivedForeignAmt = 327.50    
            .ReceivedForeignAmtInc = 376.62   
            .ReceivedUnits1 = 1    
            .ReceivedUnits1Name = "EACH"   
        End With

.Lines = New Public.PurchaseOrder.Order_Receipt_Line() { loOrder_Receipt_Line1, loOrder_Receipt_Line2 }
```

How would I loop through the query results to create the necessary receipt lines and then add each to the array of Order_receipt_Line()? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If it is for your code to use, you could create a `List(of Order_Receipt_Line)` and skip all the anguish that comes with arrays.  If you have to pass it back, then use `.ToArray()`

Comment: It's too soon to say what the code you want will look like. It depends on how you get the data from database. Will you get a DataReader object or DataTable object? What kinds of columns are in the database? Is it separate fields or one big string you must parse? Are you even talking to the DB directly, or will the data go through a web service first? You need to answer all of those questions before you're ready to ask this one.

Comment: Hi Joel, yes im talking to the database directly using execSQL to retrieve the results as per the above example the columns I'm getting back are the lineID, amounts etc.

Comment: so to elaborate further.... I've got as far as retrieving the sql query into a dataset, and then i want to iterate through the results and adding the values to the order_receipt_line()

Comment: ExecSQL.Begin

select LINE_NO, AMT_EXC, AMT_INC, UNITS, UOM from BIAUL_GOODS_RECEIPT

ExecSQL.End

 
Dim ds As DataSet = ExecSQL.ExecuteDataSet()

Dim dr As DataRow

Dim dt As DataTable

dt = ds.Tables(0)

For Each dr in dt.Rows